# Searching a Dictionary values by constraints? (C#)

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm wonder if it's possible to look through the elements in a  Dictionary to check if any exist that meet certain requirements. In my case, I've got a `Dictionary<string, Rectangle>` and for each Rectangle value, I'd like to check if a point is contained within this rectangle using the `Contains` method: (`genericRectangleValue.Contains(aPoint)`).

i.e. I'd like some functionality as would be the case with lists where I could say:

```
 dictionaryList.Exists((delegate(KeyValuePair<string, Rectangle> kvp) { return kvp.Value.Contains(e.Location); })
```

...and for the record, yup, I've considered using `List<KeyValuePair<string, Rectangle>>` for this, however other restrictions require that I go for the Dictionary approach.

It's not a critical issue on my end, however when you're stuck using a Dictionary, is there any way of doing this without going through a foreach loop?

Hope this could be of help to others in future too, Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use LINQ's `Where` on the `Values` property of the dictionary:

```
var rectsContainingLocation = dict.Values.Where(x => x.Contains(e.Location));
```

If you also need to evaluate the key in the condition, you can use `Where` directly on the dictionary:

```
dict.Where(x => condition)
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` at the top.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks Daniel! :{) I find myself constantly learning how versatile LINQ can be! Cheers! (PS Should the LINQ tag be added to this question?)

Comment: @JulianZammit: No need to add the LINQ tag. Your question wasn't *about* LINQ. LINQ only is a possible solution.